# ruby/python learning reference for Windows user

Tags: python, ruby, windows, windows-7

I am interested in learning python and ruby, but I use Windows 7. Most online articles I have seen out there are not really helpful to me since they are all explaining about python and ruby in UNIX environment.

I'd like to know if there are any good articles/books about Ruby/python programming languages that are more friendly to windows users that may be useful.

Thanks in advance. any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what they do that makes them *nix only?

Comment: Unless you're posting from the early 90s, you're not in MS-DOS.

Comment: @Glenn MS-DOS was also used in the early 00s by [Windows Me](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_ME)

Comment: use of cmd and dir instead of windows explorer, that's MS-DOS for me

Comment: @Prusswan consider switching to [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)

Comment: my point is that it has more to do with the commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html This is from Python's documentation. It has a few links in there to some standard Python resources, e.g. Dive Into Python, which I would recommend.

http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/ This blog is an alright resource; pay particular attention to the posts tagged 'faq'.

For what it's worth, though, the underlying basic logic for Python and Ruby is the same on any operating system. It's installing external libs and doing I/O that's different.

Answer (score 2):

For easy installation of Ruby on windows try [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/), and for easy installation of Python try getting the windows executable from the [Python site](http://www.python.org/getit/).

Otherwise most tutorials are platform independent, Ruby has one introductory on their [site](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/) (but use `irb` in windows now). Python has also one on their [site](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Python is very well documented:

- [Using Python in Windows](http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html) - covers the setup and use of Python in Windows
- [The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) - good introduction to the language itself (platform independent)

Answer (score 0):

Practical Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science Using Python, I have read this but it might be too easy for people with some programming experience already